# Bind failed. Error Code : -2 Message Name or service not known

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to use a [Python script](https://github.com/PaesslerAG/QoSReflect/blob/master/qosreflect.py#L1) from Git.

Its purpose is to respond to monitoring packets sent from PRTG Network Monitor.

So I downloaded it and chmoded it and executed it (-d) on the client's Debian system:

```
Linux xxxxxxxxx 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And obtained the following error:

> Bind failed.
>
> Error Code : -2 Message Name or service not known

The error apparently appears when the bind action attempts to bind port 50000 to all devices.

Is this a Debian, or system issue or a permissions issue?

Comment: Is port 50000 open on the firewall? Looks like it failed when trying to bind to that port.

Comment: what value do you have in `conf['host']`?

Comment: I figured it out : HOST is supposed to be the network interface's IP address
Thanks for your help